# How do I track/record head movement data (pitch, yaw and roll) on the oculus go? How can I implement this using Unity?

Tags: aframe, oculusgo

How do you track/record head movement data (pitch, yaw and roll) on the oculus go? Does Opentrack software/Aframe motion capture compatible on the Oculus Go?  If so, how do I implement it?

Comment: Try something first (Download the Oculus go unity plugin and check out the OVR camera rig prefab. You can get your data from there) and then come back with a more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/tour